# Change CSS Class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that I am working on and I am trying to change the CSS class on an ID and a child element.

I have a menu that has sections (example: aboutsection).  I have added an ID to the ul for that section.  What I would like to do, is look at the href attribute for each child anchor of the id, and if the current URL matches any of the links in the children, add a class to the aboutsection ID of "currentTab" and to the actual link add a class of "currentLink."

I have the following jQuery but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "aboutsection" ).each( function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == document.URL){
       $(this ).addClass( "currentLink" );
       aboutsection.addclass('currentTab');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML, there are a few syntax errors here as well

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS class. HTML has classes. CSS has class selectors. DOM has methods to get elements based on their class.

Comment: Should `$("aboutsection")` be `$(".aboutsection")`? Or is that a transcription error?

Comment: If you've added an ID for the section (and ignoring the fact you are using the wrong kind of selector), why are you using `each`? There can be only one match for an ID.

Answer (score 2):

Your general approach of using

```
$(elementId).addClass('newClassName');
```

is correct.

However, your entire loop might turn out to be useless because your selector may not return anything.

If *aboutsection* is an element's class, try

```
$('.aboutsection').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('currentLink');
});
```

which is practically the same as:

```
$('.aboutsection').addClass('currentLink');
```

If *aboutsection* is an element id (should be unique on your entire page), try

```
$('#aboutsection').addClass('currentLink');
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see I left out some things when I posted.

Comment: Here is where I am now:  I am trying to see if the children of the ID have the value of the currentURL.  I have this but it is not working...<script>

$('li#aboutsection').each(function() 
   {
     var currentUrl = window.location.href;
        
   if($(this).children.attr('href') == currentURL)
   
  {      
      $( this ).addClass( "currentTab" ); 
        }
  });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a HTML element wrapped in a tag named `aboutsection`. If this is actually the ID of your `<ul>` element, you''ll need to update your code.

Also, `aboutsection.addClass()` will have no effect, since it's undefined:

```
$(function() {
    $('#aboutsection').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('href') == document.URL)
        {
            $(this).addClass('currentLink');
            $(this).addclass('currentTab');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't it a questionable approach to loop through results whose selector applies to a unique element id?

Comment: Of course. But I didn't want to assume it was an ID, it could equally be a classname. I was merely pointing out the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help!  I am a noob at this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "aboutsection" ).each( function(){
```

is not correct.

if "aboutsection" is a class you need:

```
$( ".aboutsection" ).each( function(){
```

or if is an id you need:

```
$( "#aboutsection" ).each( function(){
```